# flex-layout within material-toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I'm currently facing a problem with layouting Angular2's material module using flex layouts.

As you're going to see in the example below as well as the attached live version, Angular2's toolbar module seems not to allow flex layouts being placed within an `mat-toolbar`

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">

    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
        <a mat-button fxFlex="auto">Item 1</a>
        <a mat-button fxFlex="auto">Item 2</a>
        <a mat-button fxFlex="auto">Item 3</a>
        <a mat-button fxFlex="auto">Item 4</a>
    </div>

</mat-toolbar>

<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
    <a mat-button>Item 1</a>
    <a mat-button>Item 2</a>
    <a mat-button>Item 3</a>
    <a mat-button>Item 4</a>
</div>
```

[Live Example](https://material-flex-toolbar.stackblitz.io)

[Editor Version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-flex-toolbar)

What I want to achieve is a placement of the buttons aligned on the right side. Outside of `mat-toolbar` everything works like a charm. Is there anything I'm missing or is that a bug which is rooted in material being still beta?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh I'm pretty sure it works, don't worry :)

Simply add `fxFlex` to your div containing all of your items.

Your issue is that the div isn't taking all the space, making you think it doesn't work.

Also, using the `fxFlex` property makes your elements take all the width they can, so use it only when a component should take all the remaining space.

[**Do you want a working blitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-flex-toolbar-5rcmbb?file=app/app.component.html) or do you want to try it and discover by yourself ?

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.
Is there any specific reason for why I'll have to add this specificly there, and why it works outside of `mat-toolbar`

Comment: There is a specific reason : using `fxLayout` set the property `display` to flex, and it behaves like an inline element instead of a block one.

Comment: Alright, so probably `mat-toolbar` already sets this property whereas it's not defined for the body tag.

Comment: Yes, the toolbar uses the flex display, just inspect it and you will see `display: flex` in its properties, hence the behavior of the div

Comment: quite annoying. because div should take full width by default anyway if someone comes from html background

Comment: @MurWade that's not true, html tags are only used to structure your pages. Css is what decides the layout. It happens that browsers consider divs to be displayed as block by default, but it's really the display property that chooses how the content is rendered.

Comment: @trichetriche HTml is for structor and css is for styling. Thanks, dude. Learn something new all the time..

Comment: @trichetriche But i think we need to use html for layout too in this day and age

Answer (score 5):

The problem is a misconception about `fxLayoutAlign`. It just aligns the content within the container and does not affect the position of the container itself. In your case, the position of the div containing all the links is not affected by the `fxLayoutAlign` attribute, but only the positioning of the links within the div.

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>Nav</span>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
        <a mat-button fxFlex="auto">Item 1</a>
        <a mat-button fxFlex="auto">Item 2</a>
        <a mat-button fxFlex="auto">Item 3</a>
        <a mat-button fxFlex="auto">Item 4</a>
    </div>

</mat-toolbar>
```

Instead, you could put something in between the elements of the right and the left that uses up all the remaining space of the container:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>Navi</span>
    <span fxFlex></span>
    <a mat-button>Item 1</a>
    <a mat-button>Item 2</a>
    <a mat-button>Item 3</a>
    <a mat-button>Item 4</a>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Yeah I see, its actually quite obvious that it didn't work. Such a dumb mistake :D